# Why does my website scroll sideways when my width is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

So my website for some reason is scrolling sideways or horizontally. It looks like the footer is causing this but I just can't figure out what the issue would be here? I think it might have something to do with the social-icons in the footer but I'm not too sure. Some guidance is appreciated

My website here: 
https://jgofficial1.000webhostapp.com/index.html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JG.OFFICAL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class= "logo">
            <!--h1>JG.OFFICIAL</h1-->
            <img src= "../images/logo.png" alt= "Hello" height ="60px" width ="310px">
        </div>       
        <nav> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href= "index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href= "work.html">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href= "contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href= "about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav> 
    </header>
    <br><br>
    <div id= "scroll1">
        <img src= "../images/scrollbutton.png" alt= "Click to scroll" height = "50" width = "50">
    </div>
    <div id= "img-wrapper">
        <img src= "../images/helloscreen.png" alt= "Hello" height= "870" width= "1228">
    </div>

    <div id= "text-wrapper2">
        <div id= "text">
            <p>Design is always in our lives, whether we like it or not.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class= "social-icons">
            <img src= "../images/fb-icon.png" alt= "Facebook" height= "45" weight= "45">
            <img src= "../images/yt-icon.png" alt= "YouTube" height= "45" weight= "45">
            <img src= "../images/instagram-icon.png" alt= "Instagram" height= "45" weight= "45">
            <img src= "../images/twitter-icon.png" alt= "Twitter" height= "45" weight= "45">
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.logo {
color: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
margin-left: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
float: left;
width: 70px;
}

body {
background-image: url("../images/background1.png");
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
}

nav {
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

nav li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 30px;
}

nav li a {
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

#scroll1 {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 200px;
}

#img-wrapper {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#text-wrapper img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#text-wrapper2 {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}

#scroll1 {
text-align: center;
}

#text p {
color: white;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
} 

footer {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 8px;
}

.social-icons {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is this solved? Can you please add a comment if not or accept an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now because of 2 reasons.

1. The image has a width of `1228px`
2. The footer has a width of `100%` + `20px` padding

Both push the content over the `100% width`. To fix it you can add something like:

```
#img-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You don't want this to happen again? Set those properties more globally and they probably will help you. So on top of your CSS you could add instead

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Why use `box-sizing: border-box;`?**

> The width and height properties include the content, **the padding and
>   border**, but not the margin.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: `/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}` https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

Your footer has `padding-left: 20px;` property. If you delete or change it, sideways scrolling will be gone.

BTW... good method to check things like that is

```
* {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #0f0 !important;
  outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```